# Redux Persist state is empty after rehydration

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist

I'm facing a strange issue. The rehydration worked in my app until I switched to remote dev tools that are being ran on a local server. Now I can see that the REHYDRATE is indeed called but all of my states remain empty after! What could be the possible cause of this? If I don't use the devtools it doesn't work either. All of my reducers return unmodified state by default. here is the configuration file:

`

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    appState: appStateReducer,
    entries: entriesReducer,
    listHelper: listHelperReducer
})

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
}

const pr = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const configureStore = () => {
    const store = createStore(pr, devToolsEnhancer({ realtime: true, hostname: 'localhost', port: 8082 }))

    const persistor = persistStore(store)
    return { persistor, store }
}

export default configureStore
```

Anyone else facing similar issue?

Reducers:

```
const initialState = {

loggedInUser: 0,
pickedEntry: null,
bulkPicker: false,
bulkPicked: []
}
const appStateReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

    case LOG_IN:
        return {
            ...state,
            loggedInUser: action.user
        }
    case PICK_ENTRY:
    return{
        ...state, 
        pickedEntry: {...action.entry}
    }
    case ACTIVATE_BULK_PICKER:
    return{
        ...state,
        bulkPicker: true
    }
    case DEACTIVATE_BULK_PICKER:
    return{
        ...state,
        bulkPicker: false,
        bulkPicked: []
    }
    case ADD_TO_BULK_PICKED:
    return{
        ...state,
        bulkPicked: [...state.bulkPicked, action.entry]
    }
    case REMOVE_FROM_BULK_PICKED:
    //remove from list
    //check if anything left then change state of bulkPicker
    let index = state.bulkPicked.findIndex((entry) => entry.key === action.entry.key)

    return{
        ...state,
        bulkPicked: [
            ...state.bulkPicked.slice(0, index),
            ...state.bulkPicked.slice(index+1)
        ]
    }

    default:
        return state
    }
}

export default appStateReducer





const initialState = {
workingCopy : [],
serverCopy: [],
pendingOperations: [],
activities: [],
issueIds: []
}
const entriesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case SET_SERVER_COPY:
        return {
            ...state,
            serverCopy: [...action.data]
        }
    case SET_WORKING_COPY:
    return {
        ...state,
        workingCopy: [...action.data]
    }
    case NEW_ENTRY:
    return {
        ...state,
        workingCopy: [...state.workingCopy, action.entry]
      }
    case STOP_ENTRY:
      const updatedList = listHelperReducer(null, {
        ...action,
        type: "END_ENTRY_UPDATE_LIST",
        entry: action.entry,
        list: state.workingCopy
      })
      return{
          ...state,
          workingCopy: [...updatedList]
      }
    case ADD_ACTIVITIES:
    return{
        ...state,
        activities: [...action.list]
    }
    case ADD_ISSUEIDS:
    return{
        ...state,
        issueIds: [...action.list]
    }

    default:
        return state
    }
}

export default entriesReducer






const listHelperReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case END_ENTRY_UPDATE_LIST:

    //find index
    const index = action.list.findIndex(
        entry => entry.key === action.entry.key
      )

    //modify list
    let listToReturn = [];
    if(index === 0)
    {
        listToReturn = [
            {
                ...action.list[0],
                endDateTime: moment(),
                totalTime: getTotal(action.list[0].startDateTime.valueOf(), moment().valueOf())
            },
            ...action.list
        ]
    }
    if(index > 0 )
    {
        listToReturn = [
            ...action.list.slice(0, index),
        {
          ...action.list[index],
          endDateTime: moment(),
          totalTime: getTotal(action.list[index].startDateTime.valueOf(), moment().valueOf())
        },
        ...action.list.slice(index + 1)
        ]
    }
    //return
     return listToReturn   

    default:
        return state
    }
}

export default listHelperReducer
```

Comment: How do your reducers look like? You need to restore the data there

Comment: I never had to restore any data to get it to work. my understanding is that it all 'just happens' for you in redux persist starting from v5. I will post the reducers as well

Answer (score 1):

To anyone trying to fix similar problem:
My issue was caused by the use of timer in my app (multiple setInterval functions). This might cause your debugger to drift away in time which is apparently causing the state not to be persisted. A restart and rebuild of the app fixed it all.